# Conditional GAN Fitting RuntimeError: Tensors must have same number of dimensions: got 4 and 1

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, reshape

This is my first time writing/experimenting with a conditional GAN implementation in PyTorch. I have used a lot of online resources to write a regular GAN which worked great. I made modifications to make a conditional GAN and the key code for that is below:

```
import torch.nn as nn
class discriminator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(discriminator, self).__init__()
        self.main = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(3, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(32),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.1, inplace=True),

            nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.1, inplace=True),

            nn.Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(128),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.1, inplace=True),

            nn.Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(256),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.1, inplace=True),

            nn.Conv2d(256, 512, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(512),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.1, inplace=True),

            nn.Conv2d(512, 1024, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(1024),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.1, inplace=True),

            nn.Conv2d(1024, 1, kernel_size=4, stride=1, padding=0, bias=False),
            nn.Flatten(),
            nn.Sigmoid()
        )

    def forward(self, x, labels):
        x = torch.cat((x, labels), dim=1)
        return self.main(x)

discriminator = discriminator()
discriminator = to_device(discriminator,device)

class generator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, latent_dim):
        super(generator, self).__init__()
        self.main = nn.Sequential(
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(latent_dim, 1024, kernel_size=4, stride=1, padding=0, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(1024),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.1, inplace=True),

            nn.ConvTranspose2d(1024, 512, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(512),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.1, inplace=True),

            nn.ConvTranspose2d(512, 256, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(256),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.1, inplace=True),

            nn.ConvTranspose2d(256, 128, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(128),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.1, inplace=True),

            nn.ConvTranspose2d(128, 64, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.1, inplace=True),

            nn.ConvTranspose2d(64, 32, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(32),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.1, inplace=True),

            nn.ConvTranspose2d(32, 3, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.Tanh()
        )

    def forward(self, z, labels):
        x = torch.cat((z, labels), dim=1)
        return self.main(x)
   
generator = generator(latent_sz)
generator = to_device(generator,device)

def train_discriminator(real_images, real_labels, opt_d):
    opt_d.zero_grad()

    real_preds = discriminator(real_images, real_labels)
    real_targets = torch.ones(real_images.size(0), 1, device=device)

    real_loss = F.binary_cross_entropy(real_preds, real_targets)
    real_score = torch.mean(real_preds).item()

    latent = torch.randn(batch_size, latent_sz, 1, 1, device=device)
    fake_labels = torch.randint(0, num_classes, (batch_size,), device=device)
    fake_images = generator(latent, fake_labels)

    fake_preds = discriminator(fake_images, fake_labels)
    fake_targets = torch.zeros(fake_images.size(0), 1, device=device)
    fake_loss = F.binary_cross_entropy(fake_preds, fake_targets)
    fake_score = torch.mean(fake_preds).item()

    loss = fake_loss + real_loss
    loss.backward()
    opt_d.step()

    return loss.item(), real_score, fake_score

def train_generator(opt_g):
    opt_g.zero_grad()

    latent = torch.randn(batch_size, latent_sz, 1, 1, device=device)
    fake_labels = torch.randint(0, num_classes, (batch_size,), device=device)
    fake_images = generator(latent, fake_labels)

    targets = torch.ones(batch_size, 1, device=device)
    score = discriminator(fake_images, fake_labels)
    loss = F.binary_cross_entropy(score, targets)

    loss.backward()
    opt_g.step()

    return loss.item()

def fit(epochs, lr, start_idx=1):
    loss_d = []
    loss_g = []
    real_scores = []
    fake_scores = []

    opt_d = torch.optim.Adam(discriminator.parameters(), lr=lr, betas=(0.5, 0.999))
    opt_g = torch.optim.Adam(generator.parameters(), lr=lr, betas=(0.5, 0.999))

    for epoch in range(epochs):
        for img, labels in tqdm(train_loader):
            img = img.to(device)
            labels = labels.to(device)

            loss, real_score, fake_score = train_discriminator(img, labels, opt_d)
            lossg = train_generator(opt_g)

        loss_d.append(loss)
        loss_g.append(lossg)
        real_scores.append(real_score)
        fake_scores.append(fake_score)

        print("Epoch [{}/{}], loss_g: {:.4f}, loss_d: {:.4f}, real_score: {:.4f}, fake_score: {:.4f}, memory_usage: {:.4f}".format(
            epoch + 1, epochs, loss, lossg, real_score, fake_score, psutil.virtual_memory()[2]))

        save_samples(epoch + start_idx, fixed_latent, fixed_labels, show=False)

    return loss_g, loss_d, real_scores, fake_scores

lr = 5e-4
epochs = 20
history = fit(epochs,lr)
```

I am running into an error when running the fit function, and I am confused on how to resolve it. The error is below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
/scratch/ipykernel_151601/1116731599.py in <module>
      1 lr = 5e-4
      2 epochs = 20
----> 3 history = fit(epochs,lr)

/scratch/ipykernel_151601/2486237605.py in fit(epochs, lr, start_idx)
     13             labels = labels.to(device)
     14 
---> 15             loss, real_score, fake_score = train_discriminator(img, labels, opt_d)
     16             lossg = train_generator(opt_g)
     17 

/scratch/ipykernel_151601/2842949976.py in train_discriminator(real_images, real_labels, opt_d)
      2     opt_d.zero_grad()
      3 
----> 4     real_preds = discriminator(real_images, real_labels)
      5     real_targets = torch.ones(real_images.size(0), 1, device=device)
      6 

~/anaconda3/envs/Ashank/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1192         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1193                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1194             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1195         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1196         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/scratch/ipykernel_151601/3323902491.py in forward(self, x, labels)
     34 
     35     def forward(self, x, labels):
---> 36         x = torch.cat((x, labels), dim=1)
     37         return self.main(x)
     38 

RuntimeError: Tensors must have same number of dimensions: got 4 and 1
```

I'm not sure where to go from here to resolve the issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated - please let me know if any additional code is needed too. Thank you in advance :).

(P.S. if anyone has a resource of a PyTorch conditional GAN for 256x256 image generation I would love to view that as a reference as well)

Comment: The images (x) and labels (labels) should have the same shape to be concatenated. the shape of the images have 4 dimentions. However, the labals have 1 dimension. Therefor, they can't be concatenated. To solve the problem you need to use an embedding layer for the labels, to embed the labels to have the same shape as the images then perform the concatenation. check this online tutorial : https://learnopencv.com/conditional-gan-cgan-in-pytorch-and-tensorflow/ . the section which is entitled "Conditional Discriminator Implementation"

Comment: Thank you, this has resolved the issue!

Comment: You are welcome. I am gonna rewrite my comment as an answer. Please Mark it as the right one.

Comment: Done - if you get a chance, I have run into a new error which I have posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76832123/cgan-training-zero-real-and-fake-loss-from-start-no-model-improvement with the same code. Would appreciate it if you could take a look as you are already familiar with my code. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to concatenate images (x) and labels (labels), they must have the same shape. Presently, the images have 4 dimensions, while the labels have only 1 dimension, which makes concatenation impossible. However, there's a solution to this issue: you can utilize an embedding layer for the labels. This embedding layer will transform the labels, bringing them to the same shape as the images, enabling successful concatenation.

To implement this approach, you can refer to an online tutorial at https://learnopencv.com/conditional-gan-cgan-in-pytorch-and-tensorflow/. Specifically, focus on the section titled "Conditional Discriminator Implementation." This tutorial will guide you through the process of using an embedding layer to harmonize the shapes of the labels and images, facilitating their concatenation efficiently.